# Error wooCommerce REST API : woocommerce_rest_cannot_view

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce, next.js

I have some difficulties accessing my wooCommerce API with react and nextjs.

I always have this message : woocommerce_rest_cannot_view
I tried the response I've seen on other thread on stackoverflow, but nothing worked for me.

Here my server.js

```
const next = require('next');
const express = require('express');
const wooConfig = require( './wooConfig' );

const WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');
// import WooCommerceRestApi from "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api"; // Supports ESM

const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
    url: wooConfig.siteUrl,
    consumerKey: wooConfig.consumerKey,
    consumerSecret: wooConfig.consumerSecret,
    wpAPI: true,
    version: 'wc/v1',
    query_string_auth: true

});

const port = 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare()
    .then(() => {
        const server = express();

        server.get('/getProducts', (req, response) => {
            WooCommerce.get('products', function (err, data, res) {
                response.json(JSON.parse(res));
            });
        })

        server.get('*', (req, res) => {
            return handle(req, res);
        });

        server.listen(port, err => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(`Ready on port ${port}`)
        })
    })
    .catch(ex => {
        console.error(ex.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    });;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

This is
queryStringAuth: true
instead of
query_string_auth: true